# C While loop stopping at EOF but printing result in a new line

Tags: c

I have this code:

```
        #include <stdio.h>
        #include <stdlib.h>
        #include <string.h>

        int main()
        {
            char vector[5][100];
            int i = 0;
            int aux = 0;
            while (i <5 && scanf("%s", vector[i])!=EOF)
            {
                i++;
                aux+= 1;
            }

            for (i=0;i<aux;i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", vector[i]);
            }
            return 0;
        }
```

Its doing what I want but still I have some problems.

**First question:** (solved)

If I input `a b c d e f g h i j` the output is:

```
 a b c d e f g h i ja
 b
 c
 d
 e
```

Want can I do to wen I press CTRL-D it prints, the first output in a new line?
Something like this:

```
 a b c d e f g h i j
 a
 b
 c
 d
 e
```

**Second question:**

If I input `a b c` why do I have to press more than one time CTRL-D to print the output?

Regards,

FAvolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
printf("\n%s", vector[i]);
```

Simply

Comment: That was so easy. Thanks.  And what about my second question?

Comment: @Favolas: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406588/eof-reading-c-c/5406652#5406652)

Comment: Sorry I missed that second part. But John's made it ;). Cheers